# Save text elements separated by tab and commas in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, text

I have the following text format in python:

```
126    attr1,attr7,attr4 and attr8
1    attr6,attr2,attr9,attr78,attr23,attr56,attr75,attr77
5    attr5,attr3,attr2
7    attr0
67    attr12,attr13,attr14
```

So i want to save the ids(126,1,5 etc) in a list and every line attributes to be saved in a list or dict. I saved the ids with the following code but i cant save the attributes. Here is my code:

```
file = open("myfile.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    nodes = []
    skills = [] #or dict()
    for x in lines:
        nodes.append(x.split('\t')[0])
        skills.append(x.split(',')[0]) #i want a list of lists or a dict with attrs
```

Comment: What's with `attr4 and attr8`? Is that a typo or a real case to be handled? How should it be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will do the trick:

```
for x in lines:
        x = x.split('\t')
        nodes.append(x[0])
        skills.append(x[1].split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather advice to use a single dictionary with `ids` as its key and `attr` as a list of values:

```
d = {}
file = open("myfile.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()   
for line in lines:
    splitted = line.split()
    d.update({splitted[0]: splitted[1].split(',')})
print(d)

# {'126': ['attr1', 'attr7', 'attr4', 'attr8'], 
#    '1': ['attr6', 'attr2', 'attr9', 'attr78', 'attr23', 'attr56', 'attr75', 'attr77'],
#    '5': ['attr5', 'attr3', 'attr2'], 
#    '7': ['attr0'], 
#   '67': ['attr12', 'attr13', 'attr14']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all attributes as joined string then :

```
attr_dict={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        attr_dict[line.split()[0]]=line.split()[1:]

print(attr_dict)
```

output:

```
{'126': ['attr1,attr7,attr4', 'and', 'attr8'], '7': ['attr0'], '5': ['attr5,attr3,attr2'], '1': ['attr6,attr2,attr9,attr78,attr23,attr56,attr75,attr77'], '67': ['attr12,attr13,attr14']}
```

If you want indivisual element then :

```
attr_dict={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=line.split()
        for sub_data in data:
            attr_dict[line.split()[0]]=sub_data.split(',')

print(attr_dict)
```

output:

```
{'126': ['attr8'], '7': ['attr0'], '5': ['attr5', 'attr3', 'attr2'], '1': ['attr6', 'attr2', 'attr9', 'attr78', 'attr23', 'attr56', 'attr75', 'attr77'], '67': ['attr12', 'attr13', 'attr14']}
```